# Convert a typed date into a date formatted cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

We have an excel file with a column called "Date", inside of which is some text, such as 28th February 2016.

How can we format this like 28/02/2016? I've tried using the format cell function but nothing changes, I've also tried using the DATEVALUE function, but it just says #VALUE! with no details about the error?

I've assumed this is something EXCEL can convert for us, but would be very grateful if anybody can enlighten me as to how to do it! We are using the latest edition of Excel for Mac if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the "th", "rd", "st" or "nd", suffixes from the end of the day number.

If all your dates are given in the same format as you've specified `28th February 2016`, then you can use a formula like the following to convert it into a date value, e.g. if the date is in A1, in another Cell/Column use:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-2,2),""))
```

Then, when you apply `Format Cells->Date` (and whatever format you want), it will display as you require.

**Explanation for the above formula**:

The goal is to substitute the th/rd/st/nd with an empty string, in numbers like "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", etc..  And, `substitute` can do this, but it needs to be told what string to replace.

To extract the th/rd/st/nd, I've used `MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-2,2)`.
This formula finds the first space, goes back two and takes two characters.  These two characters should be one of th/rd/st/nd.

Now that we have a way to extract the string to be substituted, we feed it into `SUBSTITUTE`, to get a recognisable date string.
Finally, (as you already know) use `DATEVALUE` to convert it into an actual date that can be formatted.

Comment: A very clever way to remove the unwanted ordinals! *(+1)*

Comment: "Ordinal indicator"... that's the phrase that was on the tip of my tongue as I was writing the answer, thanks @Gary'sStudent for jogging my memory.  And thanks for the comment!

Comment: @jehad Absolutely perfect. Thank you so much, for not just finding the solution but also explaining the method in such detail, It's very handy to understand how all those functions work together! Thanks again.